# How can I index the number of hosts in play based on a variable?

Tags: ansible

I want to set a fact, so that all my hosts to know the index number of a certain host in a play, based on a defined variable. I am creating a role, so the order of the hosts can change each run.

Imagine there are 3 hosts in the play. Let's say host-2 has variable `me` set to true, while the others have it set to false.

```yaml
host-1 # variable 'me' is false
host-2 # variable 'me' is true, index number is 1
host-3 # variable 'me' is false
```

Now, imagine the play is sorted like this:

```yaml
host-3 # variable 'me' is false
host-1 # variable 'me' is false
host-2 # variable 'me' is true, index number is 2
```

In this case, I want all *hosts* have a fact which contains the index number of the host in the play. Example: `the_index_host: 2`, because that is the host with the defined variable.

So far, I know how to configure Ansible to fact share amongst hosts, but got no clue how set a fact based on index number, based on a value.

```yaml
- block:

    - name: create dict of variable me amongst hosts
      set_fact:
        something: "{{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}"
      vars:
        keys: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
        values: "{{ ansible_play_hosts |
                    map('extract', hostvars, ['me'])
                    | list }}"

    - name: set_fact for index number
      set_fact:
        the_index_host: "{{ something }}"

  run_once: true
```

Comment: Could you explain the use case further? IMO, having a fact on the host is better than relying on the fact that the host is in position X in the list of hosts.

Comment: I'm working a role for MongoDB with clustering and whatnot. 

I want to automate https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mongodb/mongodb_replicaset_module.html#parameter-arbiter_at_index

Comment: So does it really matter that `mogodb-server-2` is not `mongodb-server-38`. Wouldn't it be more accurate to have a `mongodb-master` and X number of `mongodb-slaves`? Then you could filter based on `is_master: yes/no`, or does that makes no sense at all?

Comment: I get your point. But what if there are multiple slaves and/or arbiters. With my question answered I can simply add mulitple arbiters.

Comment: You could still have a fact `is_arbiter: yes/no` and filter the hosts based on that, isn't it? Or does the position of the arbiter really makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, as you can read in the docs. "Identifies the position of the member in the array that is an arbiter." It's a bit non-standard, but that is what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241046/discussion-between-kevin-c-and---).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted the host *name* instead of the index, you could do this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    primary_host: "{{ item }}"
  when: hostvars[item].me|default(false)
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

I guess if you wanted the index, that would be:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    primary_host: "{{ hostidx }}"
  when: hostvars[item].me|default(false)
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: hostidx
```